# How can I best check if two unordered pairs match?

Tags: optimization, logic, boolean-logic

I have two pairs (A,B) and (C,D).  I want to check to see if they contain the same elements.  The order is unknown.  I can accomplish this using:

```
(A == C && B == D) || (A == D && B == C)
```

But that seems like very uniform and repeated code, as though there is a way to condense it.  I cannot figure out how.  Is it possible to condense that logic?

Comment: Are the items numeric?

Comment: @MattClarke no. They are class instances.

Comment: Drat! So no fancy mathemagic possible.

Comment: What language are you using? Some languages would allow: `if ((A,B) -containedin (C,D))` (assumes same number of objects in each set) for example. APL probably has an even more compact representation

Comment: As always you can make a precompute+memory vs compute tradeoff : store a unic  id (not dependant on order) for your pairs so you can write : `if ( pair1.id == pair2.id )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(A == C && B == D) || (A == D && B == C)
```

Truth Table

```
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|   A  |  B   |  C  |   D  |   O/P  |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|   0  |   0   |   0  |   0  |    1     |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|   0   |   0  |   0  |  1   |    0     |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|   0   |   0  |  1   |  0   |    0     |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|   0   |   0  |  1   |   1  |    0     |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|   0   |   1  |   0  |   0  |   0      |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|    0  |   1  |   0  |  1   |    1     |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|    0  |   1  |  1   |  0   |   1      |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|    0  |  1   |  1   |   1  |   0      |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|   1   |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0      |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|   1   |   0  |   0  |  1   |     1    |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|   1   |   0  |   1  |  0   |    1     |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|   1   |   0  |  1   |  1   |    0     |
 +------+------+------+------+----------+
|    1  |   1  |  0   |   0  |     0    |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|   1   |   1  |   0  |  1   |     0    |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|    1  |  1   |   1  |  0   |     0    |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
|    1  |   1  |  1   |  1   |   0      |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
```

- if A, B, C, D are boolean logic then (A == C && B == D) || (A == D && B == C) is in the simplest form by K-map reduction technique and Quine-McCluskey Minimisation technique.
- if A, B, C, D are number(`ie int or float`) then you can simplyfy as `A+B==C+D` .

> if(A+B==C+D)
>       {
>             //true statment
>        }

- if A, B, C, D are string then boolean logic can't applicable. It may be simplefied but need other information in account to solve expression.

*thankyou hope you'll satisfied*